# I tried embedding QR code to my div but its not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, qr-code

I am new to js. I am trying to embed the QR code to my div with id="qrcode". I pickedup this code from the github.
When ever I try to generate the QR code it appears and then disappears in second. I tried everything but its not working.
My code is down below

```
<div class="row mb-3" id="qrcode">
</div>
<div class="row mb-3">
   <label class="col-sm-10 col-form-label" for="basic-default-company">Add Label to QR Code</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input
         type="text"
         class="form-control"
         id="basic-default-company"
         placeholder="Vehicle Reg#"
         />
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row justify-content-end">
   <div class="col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" id="generateqr" class="btn btn-primary">Generate QR</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

//Javascript down here

```
<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {

  

    $(document).on("click" , "#generateqr" , function(){
        var qrcode = new QRCode("qrcode");
        function makeCode () {      
 
        var elText = document.getElementById("basic-default-company");
    
    if (!elText.value) {
        alert("Input a text");
        elText.focus();
        return;
    }
    
    qrcode.makeCode(elText.value);

}

makeCode();

})



$("#basic-default-company").
    on("blur", function () {
        makeCode();
    }).
    on("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            makeCode();
        }
    });

});

</script>
```

I tried making it appear but nothing got fix

Comment: Where is the element "#basic-default-company"? There is none in provided html

Comment: wait let me update the html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add **event.preventDefault();** when you're performing onclick operation.

Your code should look something like this.

```
    $(document).on("click" , "#generateqr" , function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var qrcode = new QRCode("qrcode");
        function makeCode () {      
        var elText = document.getElementById("basic-default-company");
 
    if (!elText.value) {
        alert("Input a text");
        elText.focus();
        return;
    }    
    qrcode.makeCode(elText.value);
}
```

Comment: it worked
can u explain why this error occured?

Comment: This was happening because when you are submitting the form, the form is being submitted and page is getting reloaded. And to prevent this we're using event as callback function parameter and calling preventDefault().

Comment: For more details, checkout this link. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault